# GCDWebServer:In the IOS7.0 devices can not upload the video

Tags: ios

PC can be very good to achieve the video upload and download, but there are two problems in the use of IOS devices:

```
1、In the IOS7.0 devices can not upload the video, the following is log:
    [DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Did connect
    [DEBUG] Did start background task
    [DEBUG] Connection received 528 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection received 234 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection received 46 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 preflighting request "POST /upload" with 808 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 processing request "POST /upload" with 808 bytes body
    2015-12-14 10:58:34.523 GCDWebServer[1701:403846] [UPLOAD] /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5F45B407-9DA8-43D1-AADF-07CF22B1C4B2/Documents/IMG_9675.mp4
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 175 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 2 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 17
    [VERBOSE] [my localhost:80] iPad2(7.0) client:50692 200 "POST /upload" (808 | 177)
    [DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 17
2015-12-14 10:58:34.577 GCDWebServer[1701:403846] album’s name == GCDWebServer
    [DEBUG] Connection received 400 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 preflighting request "GET /list" with 400 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 processing request "GET /list" with 400 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 177 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 213 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 17
    [VERBOSE] [my localhost:80] iPad2(7.0) client's IP:50693 200 "GET /list" (400 | 390)
    [DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection received 453 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 preflighting request "GET /download" with 453 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 processing request "GET /download" with 453 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 182 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 17
    [VERBOSE] [my localhost:80] iPad2(7.0) client's IP:50694 304 "GET /download" (453 | 182)
    [DEBUG] Did disconnect
    [DEBUG] Did end background task


2、In the IPAD device can not download the video, the following is log:
    [DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Did connect
    [DEBUG] Did start background task
    [DEBUG] Connection received 427 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 preflighting request "GET /download" with 427 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 processing request "GET /download" with 427 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 398 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [ERROR] Error while writing to socket 17: Broken pipe (32)
    [DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 17
    [VERBOSE] [my localhost:80] iPad2(7.0) client's IP:50690 200 "GET /download" (427 | 197006)
    [DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection received 346 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 preflighting request "GET /download" with 346 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection on socket 17 processing request "GET /download" with 346 bytes body
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 398 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [DEBUG] Connection sent 32768 bytes on socket 17
    [ERROR] Error while writing to socket 17: Broken pipe (32)
    [DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 17
    [VERBOSE] [my localhost:80] iPad2(7.0) client's IP:50691 200 "GET /download" (346 | 131470)
    [DEBUG] Did disconnect
    [DEBUG] Did end background task
```

Do you know why? Thank you very much!

Sorry for my ignorance.